# Running unit tests with ant on an eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, ant

Alright, so I've spent a good 3 days now combing the net trying to figure out how to run some unit tests with ant from the command line for my eclipse project.

I can run the tests in Eclipse via "Run As" -> "Android JUnit Test"

What I want now is to be able to run the tests via the command line. That's it.

I can't seem to find any guides on this that were not written in 2010, but trying to follow them nonetheless I have gotten as far as installing ant and creating a build.xml file inside my project that I copy-pasta'd from a guide. Since I can only guess at what is going on in the build file (have never worked with ant before), when a problem rears its ugly head I'm pretty much SOL.

Currently when I try and run it, it says "package android.app does not exist" (I'm using the Activity class), and the same for a library jar file I've included in the project's "/libs" folder.

It seems pretty clear that somewhere I'm missing some kind of path declaration, but nothing I try seems to work.

EDIT (added code):
This is MockTester.java -

```
package com.android.mocksdktester;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

import com.mock.android.lib.*;

public class MockTester extends AndroidTestCase
{
    Activity mActivity;
    MockFeature mFeature;

    public MockTester()
    {   
    }


    public void testExists()
    {
        String test = null;
        assertNull(test);
    }
}
```

As you can see, not a lot going on. 
This is the build.xml file I've got, and as I mentioned, I can only make guesses as to what it's doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- to save as "build.xml" -->
<project name="Mock Unit Tests" default="run" basedir=".">
    <path id="junit_classpath"> 
        <pathelement location="C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705\junit.jar"/>
    </path>

    <!-- Library Project Here -->
    <fileset dir="libs" includes="*.jar"/>


    <!-- build all classes in this directory -->
    <!-- To run this: use "ant build" -->
    <!-- need to include junit.jar in the classpath -->
    <target name="build">   
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}"/>
        <echo message="Build done" />
    </target>

    <!-- Test and build all files  -->
    <!-- To run this: use "ant" (default) or "ant run" -->
    <target name="run" depends="build">
        <java taskname="Test" classname="MockTester" fork="true" failonerror="true" />
        <echo message="Unit Tests done" />
    </target>

    <!-- delete all class files -->
    <!-- To run this: use "ant clean" -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.class" />
        </delete>
        <echo message="clean done" />
    </target>

</project>
```

It was complaining about not seeing junit in the past but I managed to fix that. I'm just not sure what to do when it's missing Android-related classes, and a jar file included in the project (though I've read this is a bug).

Errors:

```
build:
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\build.xml:16: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 3 source files
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\src\com\android\mocksdktester\MockTester.java:14:error: package android.app does not exist
[javac] import android.app.Activity;
[javac]                   ^
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\src\com\android\mocksdktester\MockTester.java:15:error: package android.test does not exist
[javac] import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
[javac]                    ^
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\src\com\android\mocksdktester\MockTester.java:18:error: package com.mock.android.lib does not exist
[javac] import com.mock.android.lib.*;
[javac] ^
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\src\com\android\mocksdktester\MockTester.java:20:error: cannot find symbol
[javac] public class MockTester extends AndroidTestCase
[javac]                                  ^
[javac]   symbol: class AndroidTestCase
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\src\com\android\mocksdktester\MockTester.java:22:error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     Activity mActivity;
[javac]     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class Activity
[javac]   location: class MockTester
[javac] C:\<my workspace>\mock\mock_sdk_android\trunk\source\MockSDKTest\src\com\android\mocksdktester\MockTester.java:23:error: cannot find symbol
[javac]     MockFeature mFeature;
[javac]     ^
[javac]   symbol:   class MockFeature
[javac]   location: class MockTester
[javac] 6 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No explanation what you did or what is failing? How is your project organized?

Ant uses the [`<junit>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html) task to execute your JUnit tests. You must make sure that you have the JUnit jar in your `<junit>` classpath.

Normally, it's a two step process:

- Compile your unit tests.
- Run `<junit>` to execute your tests. The `formatter` will specify how you want the tests formatted. You could create an XML output, and then run a XSLT transformation on it.

When you run your `<junit>` tests, you use the `<test>` or `<batchtest>` sub-tasks to the `<junit>` tasks to actually run the test, and then use `<formatter>` to format your tests for readable output.

I'm not building an Android app, but here's a sample of my Junit test:

```
<property name="target.dir"   value="${basedir}/target"/>
<property name="main.destdir" value="${target.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="test.srcdir"  value="${basedir}/src/test/java"/>
<property name="test.destdir" value="${target.dir}/test-classes"/>

<!-- Path for all jars required for compiling your actual source -->
<path id="main.classpath">
     <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib"/>
<path>

<!-- Includes JUnit.jar and the main.classpath jars too -->
<path id="test.classpath">
     <fileset dir="${basedir}/test-lib"/>
     <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib"/>
</path>
<mkdir dir="${test.destdir}"/>

<!-- Compile tests -->
<javac destdir="${test.destdir}"
    fork="false"/>
    <src path="${test.srcdir}"/>
    <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
    <classpath refid="${main.destdir}"/>
```

```
<!-- Execute all classfiles you've compiled in test-classes directory -->
<junit fork="true"
    maxmemory="128m"
    includeAntRuntime="true">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${main.destdir}"/>
        <pathelement path="${test.destdir}"/>
    </classpath>
    <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
    <formatter type="plain"/>
    <batchtest
        todir="${junit.batchtest.todir}">
        <fileset dir="${test.destdir}"/>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

Comment: Hmm alright, thank you for the info. I didn't know it was a two step process. I think I am adding JUnit to the classpath; does mine look right?

Comment: You need to `<javac>` to compile your unit tests. Include the directory where your first `<javac>` that was used to compile the code put the classfiles ANT the JUnit jar. Then, you can either pick and choose tests to run via the `<test>` subtask (good if you have a program that runs your unit tests, or use the `<batchtest>` to run all unit tests that were compiled by your `<javac>` task. I'll update my answer to include the initial compile

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help David. I actually decided to drop trying to use ant since all I really wanted to do what run the unit tests via command line, which can be done using the `am instrument` command in the adb shell (which I found by going over the android dev docs agian).

So, I'm not really sure I'm doing the right thing here, because while I found the answer to what I really wanted, it isn't exactly the answer to the question I asked, which was how to run tests via command line *through ant*.

My particular command looks like this: `adb shell am instrument -w com.android.mocksdktester.test/andro
id.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`

There were a couple gotchas for me before I got this to work.

1. You need to make sure you have both the application you are testing *and* the test application installed on your emulator/device before the test will work.
2. I created the test project following http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html from the command line and then imported the project into eclipse. I saw that the package name was the same as the package of the application I was trying to test, and I thought that was wrong so I changed it to something else, and it broke. So, don't do that :P (unless you know how to change it and not break it).
3. For the longest time I was trying to run `adb shell am instrument -w com.android.mocksdktester/andro
   id.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`. I didn't have `.test` at the end of the package name, and from what I could tell, there was no indication that I needed it. The documentation said `"The Android package name of the test package."` which was `com.android.mocksdktester`. The only reason I figured out to add `.test` to the end of it was because I had found the command `adb shell pm list instrumentation` from a different question which I think lists all the instrumentation packages that are currently on your emulator/device, and one of the items in the list was

   > instrumentation:com.android.mocksdktester.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner (target=com.android.mocksdktester).